# Spring AOP: inherited methods

Tags: java, spring, inheritance, aop

I am using Spring AOP 4.0.x.
I have the next classes:

```
class A {
    public void methodA() {
        // ...
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public void methodB() {
        // ...
    }
}

class C extends A {
    public void methodC() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to add an after throwing advice **only** for the inherited **methodA inside the class B**.

The problem is that if I use the next pointcut to achieve it

```
execution(* package.B+.method*(..))
```

then the advice is executed even if the inherited **methodA** inside the class **C** throws an exception.

How to let Spring know that the **methodA** has thrown an exception as an inherited method of class **B**, not **C** one?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

The only solution I have found by now is to use the next expression:

```
execution(* package.B.method*(..)) || 
    (execution(* package.A.method*(..)) && target(package.B))
```

, but looks like there is more brief and elegant solution.